# Error when taking the length of an input

Tags: javascript

I want to use `.length` in this script, but when I add `.length`, the script fails.

The input:

```
<input type="text" name="myform" class="myform" placeholder="Full Name" value="" maxlength="20"  minlength="6" pattern="[a-zA-Z-']+.{6,40}">
```

Original (working) code :

```
if ($.trim($("input[name=myform]").val()) === "") {
    $("input[name=myform]").addClass("merror");
    return false;
}
});
$("input").change(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("merror");
}).trigger("change");
```

After adding `.length`:

```
if ($.trim($("input[name=myform]").length === 6)) {
    $("input[name=myform]").addClass("merror");
    return false;
}

$("input").change(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("merror");
}).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misplaced a `)` or two.

Adding some space to your `if` statement shows the problem:

```
if ($.trim(  
            $("input[name=myform]").length === 6)
          ) {
```

You need a closing `)`. But even then, you're taking the length of `$("input[name=myform]")` -- which is the list of `input`s with the name "myform". It will certainly be `1`.

You want to take the length of the *value* of that input (after trimming), like so:

```
 if ($.trim( $("input[name=myform]").val() ).length === 6)
 {
```

Comment: if ($.trim(  
            $("input[name=xxxx]").length === 6)
          ) {  $("input[name=xxxxx]").addClass("merror"); return false;}

Comment: You haven't shown how this code is called, or how its results are used, so I don't know what to say about that. Please update the question with all of the details.

Comment: I want to raise error when you put 6 characters on a client file name, but length does not work Always shows me wrong even if you put 20 characters

Comment: I see no reason `length` would be involved with that code. If you have another question, please [ask another question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).